# Django_Tables2 Accessor / Related Fields

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have the following constellation of Tables, which are linked via FK's:
(omitted a few fields for better readability)

```
class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_detail = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, verbose_name='Product Detail Name')
    materialcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Material-Code')
    billing_model = models.ForeignKey(BillingModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....

--------------

class MinimumRevenue(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_model = models.ForeignKey(BillingModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minimum_revenue = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, verbose_name='Minimum Revenue')
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_detail = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Product Detail')
    event_type_assignment = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Event Type Assignment')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Start Date', default=get_first_of_month)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='End Date')
    ....
```

And a Table (Django_Tables2) which points to the MinimumRevenue Model (which works as designed), now I would like to also show some more related fields in my Table:

```
class MinimumRevenueTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.LinkColumn('non_voice:minimum_revenue_update', orderable=False, text='Edit', args=[A('pk')])
    invoice_text = tables.TemplateColumn(
        '<data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{record.context}}">{{record.invoice_text|truncatewords:2}}')
    start_date = tables.DateColumn(format='Y-m-d')
    end_date = tables.DateColumn(format='Y-m-d')
    foreigncolumn = tables.Column(accessor='productdetail.materialcode')

    class Meta:
        model = MinimumRevenue
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
        fields = ('operator', 'billing_model', 'minimum_revenue', 'product', 'product_detail', 'event_type_assignment',
                  'start_date', 'end_date', 'invoice_text', 'currency', 'foreigncolumn')
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover', }
```

The foreigncolumn column is never filled, just showing '-', I also tried it with other columns of ProductDetail, but never get any result, would really appreciate any solutions!

Comment: Ok, I don't get it, this works:     foreigncolumn = tables.Column(accessor='product_detail.billing_model') --> why is the Model ProductDetal becoming product_detail in this synatx???

Comment: Shouldn't you go through ```product_detail``` field in MinimumRevenue Model to grab it?
```foreigncolumn = tables.Column(accessor='product_detail.materialcode')``` 
Otherwise it's not clear which relation it should take.

Comment: Aha, so the first part of the accessor actually is the foreign key in my current model and not the real Model Name? Would make sense since it is working, the documentation could really make some better examples